# Spring Boot autowire dependency in TestExecutionListeners

Tags: spring-boot

Situation: There is a server that will accept test results that I hand off to it, but only given the proper authorization and client configuration. So I wrote a client class as a bean that loads the correct credentials from application.properties (in the same manor you would connect to a database with credentials and spring's properties). I now want to write a testng listener that uses this client to do this. Doing my research, I found that the Spring thing to do should be to extend `AbstractTestExecutionListener`.

So if I autowire my client as a class member, like this `@Autowired private MyClient client;` I can see that the bean is being created correctly, however if I try to use it in my listener like this:

```
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS, listeners = {MyListener.class})
public abstract class MyTestParent extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests { //...
```

I can see that beans aren't autowired which leads me to believe that these listeners are instantiated outside the spring context as beans themselves.

How can I write a listener (specific to either spring or testng) that can have dependencies wired into it from the Spring context? What if I wanted to push results to some other arbitrary test-results repository such as a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring does not autowire dependencies in TestListeners.
But you can access the beanfactory and use it to autowire the listener itself :

```
public class CustomTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    TestSupport support;

@Override
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    //get the beanfactory and use it to inject into this
    testContext.getApplicationContext()
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .autowireBean(this);

    //now use the autowired field 
    support.beforeClass();
}
```

...
}

Comment: This isn't what I ended up doing, but it does directly answer my question. Thank you